# .net core seo ссылки

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, seo, asp.net-core-mvc

Возник вопрос в .net core. В базе данных хранятся категории услуг и отображаются в view. При переходе на них, например на "установка сплит систем" формируется url вида [https://домен.ru/установка_сплит_систем](https://%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD.ru/%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82_%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC). Как сделать  латинские символы:
[https://домен.ru/ustanovka_split_sistem](https://%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD.ru/ustanovka_split_sistem)? Просто специалисты по seo твердят о латинских символах в URI!!!

Comment: Исправляйте маршруты. Покажите как вы прописали маршруты в своем приложении.

Comment: Маршрутизация в контроллере через атрибут Route( ["controller"]/{name}_{id} ) , где name это title услуги из базы и id -этой услуги...в базе заголовок по русски.